# Listview items with fixed height and horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the list items just like **windows explorer list view**.

i.e. **LIstview** div should have fixed height and list items should scroll horizontally.Listview should look something similar to this. After first column list items should float to second column and so on.

Grid view and Details view I am able to achieve but facing issues with this. Please help

```css
.list-items {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #999;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}

.list-items .fa {
  color: #d4b670;
}

.list-view {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="listview">
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
    <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Listview should look something similar to this. After first column list items should float to second column and so on.  List items should render columnwise not rowwise ..I.e. Folder1 is first row first column ..folder 2 is 2nd row first column so on ..once Fixed height is reached it should float to next column

[image: List View]

Answer (score 0):

create a parent div that holds few folders divs, this parent div will act as a row. create how many u want and float the parent divs.
hope this code is useful.

https://codepen.io/NavaneethVijay/pen/Yejxga

```
.list-items {
    font-size:16px;
    margin:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#999;
    display: inline-block;
}

.listview .row {
    float: left;
}

.list-items .fa {
    color:#d4b670;
}

.listview{

    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

<div class="listview">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder4</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder5</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-items">
            <span class="fa fa-folder"></span>
            <span class="myfolder-name">My Folder</span>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: list items should render columnwise not rowwise ..I.e. Folder1 is first row first column ..folder 2 is 2nd row first column so on ..once Fixed height is reached it should float to next column